# Angular + Dart JS Error when routing to another page

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to develop a simple Dart + Angular2 web application.
I've done the [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/) tutorial and i've been reading about Dart.

I have a problem that i can't seem to understand.

I'm trying to build a simple app that has a list of users and then allows you to select a user and edit it.

I have 3 dart files in my project, the app_component, the user_list and the user_edit:

This are my dart files:

**app_component.dart**

```
@RouteConfig(const [
    const Route(path: '/users', name: 'UsersList', component: UserListComponent),
    const Route(path: '/user/:id', name: 'UserDetail', component: UserEditComponent)
])

@Component(
    selector: 'users',
    templateUrl: 'app_component.html',
    directives: const [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: const [UserService, ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
)
class AppComponent {}
```

**user_list_component.dart**

```
@Component(
    selector: 'user-list',
    templateUrl: 'user_list_component.html'
)
class UserListComponent implements OnInit {
    List<User> users;

    final UserService _userService;
    final Router _router;

    UserListComponent(this._userService, this._router);

    Future<Null> ngOnInit() async {
       users = await _userService.getUsers();
    }

    void gotoUser(User user) {
        _router.navigate(["UserDetail", {'id': user.userId.toString()}]);
    }
}
```

**user_edit_component.dart**

```
@Component(
    selector: 'user-detail',
    templateUrl: 'user_edit_component.html'
)
class UserEditComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input()
    User user;

    final UserService _userService;
    final RouteParams _routeParams;

    UserEditComponent(this._userService, this._routeParams);

    Future<Null> ngOnInit() async {
        var userId = _routeParams.get('id');
        if(userId != null) {
            user = await _userService.getUser(userId);
        }
    }
}
```

In user_list view, i display the user data as a table, and i have a click event on each row, that i expect to take me to the user edit page.

**user_list_component.html**

```
...
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of users" (click)="gotoUser(user)">
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
...
```

Running this on Dartium, gives me the expected result, and i can navigate between the user list and the user edit page, but it fails on every other browser and the browser doesn't give any info in the error.

This is the error i get

```
js_helper.dart:1729 Uncaught 
  wrapException @ js_helper.dart:1729
  call$0 @ async_patch.dart:561
  _microtaskLoop @ schedule_microtask.dart:41
  dart._startMicrotaskLoop @schedule_microtask.dart:50
  dart._AsyncRun__initializeScheduleImmediate_internalCallback.call$1 @async_patch.dart:54
  call$0 @ js_helper.dart:2409
  eval$1 @ isolate_helper.dart:462
  _callInIsolate @isolate_helper.dart:54
  dart.invokeClosure @ js_helper.dart:2409
  (anonymous function) @ js_helper.dart:2429
```

I'm trying to learn Angular with Dart, and i'm probably doing something wrong here, but i can't find out what and i'd really appreciate some help :)

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1:**

**pubspec.yaml**

```
name: test_app
description: Test App
version: 0.0.1
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.13.0 <2.0.0'
dependencies:
  angular2: 2.0.0-beta.21
  browser: ^0.10.0
  dart_to_js_script_rewriter: ^1.0.1
transformers:
- angular2:
  platform_directives:
  - 'package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_DIRECTIVES'
  platform_pipes:
  - 'package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_PIPES'
  entry_points: web/main.dart
- dart_to_js_script_rewriter
```

**EDIT 2:**

**user_edit_component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="user != null">
    <label>User </label><span>{{user.userId}}</span>
    <label>Name: </label><span>{{user.fullName}}</span>
    <label>Domain: </label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="user.domain" placeholder="domain"/>
</div>
```

**EDIT 3:**

```
class User {
  String userId;
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String fullName;
  String email;
  String domain;
  List<String> roles;

  User(this.userId, this.domain);
}
```

Comment: Are you using `@MirrorsUsed()` anywhere? Can you please add your `pubspec.yaml`?

Comment: I'm sorry, forgot to add my pubspec.yaml.
And no, i'm not using `@MirrorsUsed()`.

Comment: Everything you posted seems fine. Are you loading the app into Chrome (or what your other browser is) from `pub serve` or from `pub build`?

Comment: I'm loading from `pub serve`, and i tried to load it in Chrome, in Firefox and in IE11.

Comment: What Dart version are you using? Did you update Dartium to match the Dart version you are using?

Comment: I'm using Dart version 1.19.0 and Dartium 1.19.0.0.
It works in Dartium.

It fails in Chrome 52.0.2743.116 m, Firefox 38.2.1 and IE 11. All with the same error.

Comment: Can you please try to delete the `.pub` directory in your project, then run `pub get` again and launch the app again.

Comment: I've deleted `.pub`, run `pub get` and relaunched and i still have the error.

Comment: But it's working with the Tour of Heroes examples?

Comment: Yes, the Tour of Heroes works.

At first i thought it could be the place where i'm trying to handle the click, but i've tried doing it exactly like the Tour of Heroes and it gave me the same error.

Comment: When exactly do you get the error. When you click on a routerLink or when you load the app, ...?

Comment: I can list the users, but when i click on a row, i can see that the `gotoUser(User user)` is called, it runs the `ngOnInit()` of the `user_edit_component`, the data is returned from the service, but after that it gives the error and never renders the page.

Comment: Can you try to use different HTML than `<tbody>`, `<tr>`, and `<td>` (no table related elements)? Do you have any bindings inside `<tr>` or `<td>`?

Comment: Inside the `<tr>` i have bindings to some properties of the user.

I've changed the table to a `<ui>` with a `<li *ngFor="let user of users" (click)="gotoUser(user)">` and i have the same error.

Comment: Can you try to comment these out to narrow down where the error can happen.

Comment: Hmm, i think my problem is with the user_edit_component.html and the .dart.  I was able to render the page without having any bindings on it. It must be one of those small errors. I'll add the properties one by one and i'll get back :)

Comment: I've added my user_edit_component.html. It seems that if i comment out the line `<input [(ngModel)}="user.domain" placeholder="domain"/>` it renders the page. I've checked and double checked the documentation and think i don't have any error there.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this input except the typo (see my answer). Are you sure `domain` always contains a string?

Comment: Tha `domain` is a `String` yes, but it can be `null` or empty

Comment: It shouldn't really matter. `null` and empty should work as well. I also can't see any error. Can you please also add the `User` class?

Comment: added the User class

Comment: I'll take another approach, i'll download the `Tour of Heroes` and try to edit it to my needs instead of creating my project.

Comment: I'd try next to `print('user.domain: ${user?.domain}');` after `user = await _userService.getUser(userId);` and run it in browsers where the app fails to check what it prints there to the browser console.

Comment: I printed the values as you said, and it print my user data that comes from the webservice. I also started to change the ´Tour of Heroes` to accommodate my need and it is working now.

Answer (score 1):

NgModel is part of the forms directives and not the core, so it seems that you're missing the `FORM_DIRECTIVES` bag of directives in your list of directives for the `user_edit_component` component.

```
@Component(
    selector: 'user-detail',
    templateUrl: 'user_edit_component.html',
    directives: const [FORM_DIRECTIVES]
)
```

In Angular2 Dart you have to explicitly list all the directives that you want to make available in your template, unless you make them globally available through the pubspec.yaml.

Comment: That's not the case if they are listed in `pubspec.yaml` transformers section as shown in the question (`platform_directives`, `platform_pipes`). This way built-in and custom directives and pipes can be made globally available.

Comment: You're right, edited answer to reflect that it probably is the FORM_DIRECTIVES then.